# portainer got error after restarting hosts

Tags: docker-swarm

Im using portainer for docker swarm.
Version: portainer/portainer-ce:2.11.0-alpine.
Via web UI of portainer, I cannot show any data of my docker swarm (stacks, services,...).

When I show service list of docker swarm:

```
docker service ls
ID             NAME                                              MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                               PORTS                         
okczbojnoyvf   portainer_agent                                   global       4/4        portainer/agent:2.11.0-alpine                       
77286g12ru0q   portainer_portainer                               replicated   1/1        portainer/portainer-ce:2.11.0-alpine                *:8000->8000/tcp, *:9443->9443/tcp, *:29000->9000/tcp
yifs4y2rplzj   swarmpit_agent                                    global       4/4        swarmpit/agent:latest                               
2swudmbmtiec   swarmpit_app                                      replicated   0/1        swarmpit/swarmpit:latest                            *:888->8080/tcp
tdwb6iy2ykie   swarmpit_db                                       replicated   1/1        couchdb:2.3.0                                       
buzdxnbpn5da   swarmpit_influxdb                                 replicated   0/1        influxdb:1.7
```

The logs of swarmpit_influxdb:

```
docker service logs -f swarmpit_influxdb
swarmpit_influxdb.1.q7eslgsw84e6@docker03.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:45:02.630346Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0mgkiE9W000 version=1.7.11 branch=1.7.11 commit=f11ad4780c8a61108108a18b141c1d067d920a80
swarmpit_influxdb.1.q7eslgsw84e6@docker03.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:45:02.630394Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0mgkiE9W000 version=go1.13.8 maxprocs=16
swarmpit_influxdb.1.q7eslgsw84e6@docker03.hkl    | run: create server: rename /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.dbtmp /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.db: file exists
swarmpit_influxdb.1.ll9hgesyoafm@docker03.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:45:26.634682Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0mgkjgvW000 version=1.7.11 branch=1.7.11 commit=f11ad4780c8a61108108a18b141c1d067d920a80
swarmpit_influxdb.1.ll9hgesyoafm@docker03.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:45:26.634730Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0mgkjgvW000 version=go1.13.8 maxprocs=16
swarmpit_influxdb.1.ll9hgesyoafm@docker03.hkl    | run: create server: rename /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.dbtmp /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.db: file exists
swarmpit_influxdb.1.7gf1le5k3lba@docker03.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:45:45.832173Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0mgkkrv0000 version=1.7.11 branch=1.7.11 commit=f11ad4780c8a61108108a18b141c1d067d920a80
swarmpit_influxdb.1.7gf1le5k3lba@docker03.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:45:45.832223Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0mgkkrv0000 version=go1.13.8 maxprocs=16
swarmpit_influxdb.1.7gf1le5k3lba@docker03.hkl    | run: create server: rename /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.dbtmp /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.db: file exists
swarmpit_influxdb.1.082iajvhfvfd@docker04.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:46:13.431821Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0mgkmYil000 version=1.7.11 branch=1.7.11 commit=f11ad4780c8a61108108a18b141c1d067d920a80
swarmpit_influxdb.1.082iajvhfvfd@docker04.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:46:13.431878Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0mgkmYil000 version=go1.13.8 maxprocs=16
swarmpit_influxdb.1.082iajvhfvfd@docker04.hkl    | run: create server: rename /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.dbtmp /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.db: file exists
swarmpit_influxdb.1.nlktc5auq3yx@docker04.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:46:30.722784Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0mgknbGW000 version=1.7.11 branch=1.7.11 commit=f11ad4780c8a61108108a18b141c1d067d920a80
swarmpit_influxdb.1.nlktc5auq3yx@docker04.hkl    | ts=2024-01-12T18:46:30.722830Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0mgknbGW000 version=go1.13.8 maxprocs=16
swarmpit_influxdb.1.nlktc5auq3yx@docker04.hkl    | run: create server: rename /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.dbtmp /var/lib/influxdb/meta/meta.db: file exists
```

And then I check the file meta.db in each host:

```
[root@docker03 meta]# pwd
/data/swarmpit/influxdb/meta
[root@docker03 meta]# ls -la
ls: cannot access meta.db: No such file or directory
total 9
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan 13 02:32 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 4096 Sep 27  2021 ..
-?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? meta.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   20 Jan 13 02:32 meta.dbtmp
```

Portainer worked find, but after restarting Nodes, the error occurs.

How to fix this ? Is it safe if I remove meta.db file ?

Thank you all.